# Kotlin: How to access a field with the same name as an extension?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I have the following field extension

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

val Enum<*>.serializedName: String get() = javaClass.getField(name).getAnnotation(SerializedName::class.java).value
```

Now if my enum has the same field name as `serializedName` extension, how could I access the extension field.
My current approach is to cast to Enum

```
enum class MyEnum {
    FIELD_1,
    FIELD_2
    ;
    val serializedName = (this as Enum<*>).serializedName 
}
```

Comment: Your solution is good enough. Ideally you shouldn't write extensions that conflict with existing field names, especially in your own project scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. It described in the official kotline documentation https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html

> If a class has a member function, and an extension function is defined which has the same receiver type, the same name, and is applicable to given arguments, the member always wins. For example: